# How to pass array in where condition? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

If I have data like this

For example, my table is country table

First data :

> id = 1; name = england; deleted_by = 1, 3

Second data :

> id = 2; name = spain; deleted_by = 2, 4

I try like this :

```
Country::whereIn('deleted_by', $user_id)->get();
```

But seems my case can not use `whereIn`

For example, I want to show data has an user_id = 1

How can I do it?

Note :

deleted_by = the data deleted by the user id

$user_id = user id that is being logged

Comment: Try changing `where()` condition to `find()` Add the id only inside the find

Comment: Just to clarify, your `deleted_by` column can contain multiple ids separated by a comma??

Comment: @Ross Wilson, No. It only has two id

Comment: If it's only 2 ids (strictly) then you could have had a `deleted_by_one` and `deleted_by_two` columns instead of mixing them up.

Comment: Remember, 1st normal form requires each row column intersection of a base table to be atomic (with respect to the context), so if you have a column that holds user identifiers, then each row will need to have a single user identifier stored in that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works. You can do something like this:

```
Country::where('deleted_by', 'like', ','.$user_id.',')->get();
```

And store data as `,2,4,`

But a much better way is to keep user IDs in a separate pivot table and use [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: I modify to be : `Country::where('deleted_by', 'like', '%'.$user_id.'%')`

Comment: @samueltoh this will not work, because if user ID is 1, it will also get data for users with IDs `12`, `61`, `212` etc.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I need to use `not like`. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814099/how-can-i-use-not-like-on-laravel-mongodb. Maybe you can help me

Comment: @samueltoh do the same, but use `'not like'` instead of `'like'`

Comment: I use this library : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. Seems the library not support `not like`

Comment: You way : `Country::whereIn('deleted_by', 'like', ','.$user_id.',')->get();`.  It does not work. There exist error : `ErrorException in Builder.php line 915:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Why not use where like this : `Country::where('deleted_by', 'like', ','.$user_id.',')->get();`. It works

Comment: @samueltoh omg, sorry, I've copy and pasted your code and modified it. Of course it should be `where()`. )

Comment: No problem. Thanks for you help