# How can I use "not like" on laravel mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I see here : https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I try :

```
$user = Comment::where('body', 'like', '%spam%')->get();
```

It works

But when I try :

```
$user = Comment::where('body', 'not like', '%spam%')->get();
```

It does not work

Seems the library not support not like

Whether there are any people who know how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `like` is converted to regex anyway, so you can do it as `not regexp`:

```
$user = Comment::where('body', 'not regexp', '/spam/i'))->get();
```

Comment: I try to implement to my case like this : `Comment::where('deleted_by', 'not regexp', '/'.auth()->user()->id.'/i')->get();`. It does not work

Comment: Should like this : `Comment::where('deleted_by', 'not regexp', '/.*'.auth()->user()->id.'/i')->get();`

Comment: First of all, "It does not work" is not a problem statement (c). Secondly, there is no difference between `/18/i` and `/.*18/i`. Do you have any error, or just don't get expected results?

Answer (score 0):

`not like` is working in 2023 for `jenssegers/mongodb` v3.9. We can also see the operator `not like` listed under the `$operators` array inside the package source code here [src/Query/Builder.php](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/src/Query/Builder.php#L81).

For example, in a collection with 10 documents:

Supposedly, the following query will return 3

```php
Comment::where('body', 'like', '%spam%')->count();
```

Then the the following query will return 7

```php
Comment::where('body', 'not like', '%spam%')->count();
```